# Querying child elements of a component when useShadowDom = false

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm using `useShadowDom: false` with my components in an attempt to support more browsers without having to use the troublesome web_components polyfill.  With the shadow DOM enabled, I would do something like this:

```dart
void onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot root) {
  root.querySelector('.btn-go-back').onClick.listen((e) {
    if (goBackHandler != null) {
      goBackHandler();
    }
  });
}
```

`onShadowRoot` would run *after* my component's template was loaded and therefore all the components elements exist in the DOM.  Without Shadow DOM enabled, I inject the component's root element in the constructor, and do something like this:

```dart
MyComponent(this._root){
  _root.querySelector('.btn-go-back').onClick.listen((e) {
    if (goBackHandler != null) {
      goBackHandler();
    }
  });
}
```

This doesn't work because the component's template hasn't been loaded into the DOM yet, so the root element doesn't have any children to query yet.

I've tried implementing AttachAware, and querying the root element in the `attach()` method, and the template isn't loaded at that point either.

So, if I'm not using the shadow DOM, how can I know when the template has been loaded into the DOM so I can query elements within my component?

**Edit**

Attempting to use `ShadowRootAware` and `onShadowRoot` with `useShadowRoot: false` will result in the following error if you try to query against the provided `ShadowRoot` object:

```
Unsupported operation: Not supported

STACKTRACE:
#0      EmulatedShadowRoot._notSupported     (package:angular/core_dom/emulated_shadow_root.dart:5:21) 
#1      EmulatedShadowRoot.querySelector (package:angular/core_dom/emulated_shadow_root.dart:32:63)
```

I also tried a combination of:

- Injecting the root element in the constructor and
- querying against the root element within `onShadowRoot` which worked, kinda, but now I'm seeing this in the console output:

---

```
[WebPlatformShim] WARNING: Failed to set up Shadow DOM shim for [find-result].

InvalidCharacterError: The string contains invalid characters. '[find-result]' is not a valid attribute name.
```

So, for some reason, even with `useShadowDom` set to false on all my Components, it's still attempting to use the ShadowDom shim.  I'm assuming this is because it is because I've implemented `ShadowRootAware` which constructs an `EmulatedShadowRoot`.  So, I think I need a solution that avoids `onShadowRoot`

Comment: The error message seems to be caused by this bug https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1189

Comment: Yep, I saw that (noted in comment to Alexandre).  Funny thing is, it still fails when I use a class selector, so `.find-result` instead of `[find-result]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query the template of a emulated component as follows:

```
class Component implements ShadowRootAware {
  Element el;

  Component(this.el);

  void onShadowRoot(_) {
    this.el.querySelector('.blah');
  }
}
```

The error message:

```
[WebPlatformShim] WARNING: Failed to set up Shadow DOM shim for [find-result].
```

is caused by the css shim. This is one of the limitations of the shim (you can use only element selectors).

You can disable the css shim. Then you will not see the error, but you won't have CSS encapsulation.

See more here:

https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/wiki/CSS-Shim

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm handling the css encapsulation manually, and in fact, thought that was already necessary when useShadowDom was set to false.

Comment: Victor, the fix was slightly more involved than what was documented on the WIKI.  See the diff here: https://github.com/bgourlie/noBS/commit/84d4e9f129a83a9ea41748c9048907c0936d8e75#diff-96fa981a11712e552bdbb24051a99141.  Basically, you need to create two implementations of NoShim.  This might only be necessary to satisfy the type checker, which wouldn't otherwise matter.  There is also the somewhat obscure import: `import 'package:angular/core_dom/module_internal.dart'`

Comment: I took the liberty of modifying the wiki with your code, w.brian

Answer (score 2):

We schedule child elements querying on the next event loop iteration. I'm not aware about particular internal implementation details, but it reliably works fine for us:

```dart
MyComponent(Element root) {
  // Schedule child elements querying on the next event loop iteration when
  // AngularDart will render the child DOM.
  new Future(() {
    root.querySelector('.btn-go-back').onClick.listen((e) {
      if (goBackHandler != null) {
        goBackHandler();
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Or just move the code you pass to the `Future` to the `onShadowRoot()` method like I argued in the comment to Alexandres answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `onShadowRoot` even with `useShadowDom: false`. However the parameter provided is not a `ShadowRoot` object.

Comment: I tried this.  I edited my question with the reason this doesn't work.

Comment: What is the type of your `root` variable ? It should be `Element` and not `ShadowRoot`.

Comment: When injecting the element into the constructor?  Just `Element`.

Comment: Strange... Did you look at all the `find-result` in your code ? It seems related to that name.

Comment: The error is related to [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1189) bug, but should be a non-issue because I don't want the shadowDom or any shims involved at all.  I tried changing the selector to my `find-result` component to a class `.find-result` and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I think in this case you should either use `document.querySelector()` or use the `_root` you inject in the 2nd code snippet inside `onShadowRoot` like `_root.querySelector()`. If there isn't a shadowRoot you can't use it as an anchor for querying.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I did attempt to query the _root element injected via constructor in the onShadowRoot method (see the edit in my question).  It seems to me that when constructing the EmulatedShadowRoot (shadowDom: false and implement ShadowRootAware) the web platform shim attempts to do some stuff that is failing, even when not querying the shadowRoot object.